# AppEngine Zone (Data Center)

Tags: google-app-engine

How is possible to know the current Zone (as in: us-central1-a, b, f) where an AppEngine application is currently running?

Cloud SQL allows us to specify that its location should follow an AppEngine app, but for general GCE instances there isn't a similar option (since they obviously aren't managed so static to one zone...)

We would like to create GCE instances in the same zone as the app to reduce latency.

One way we thought of was to start one instance in each zone and then test the latency but we would naturally prefer a simpler approach to find this out...

Comment: Keep in mind that different zones don't necessarity mean different data centers. You might be better off actually testing latency. See https://gigaom.com/2014/03/02/5-things-you-probably-dont-know-about-google-cloud/